# Image viewer without antialiasing

Tags: software-recommendation, image-viewers

I need an image viewer with the following features:

1. Infinite zoom in and zoom out.
2. No antialiasing. I want to see pixels as is and as close as I want to.
3. Mouse control.
4. (optional) Show pixel coordinates and RGBa value.

I tried shotwell (the default on my system), gpicview, sxiv and feh but none of them is both handy enough and satisfies my needs.

Gimp does the thing, but it is too heavy to be run just as image viewer.

Comment: fwiw in sxiv antialiasing can be disabled by hitting `a`; it has no infinite zoom though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geeqie is lightweight and will do the job.

To install `sudo apt-get install geeqie`

In order to disable anti-aliasing go to **Edit > Preferences > Preferences > Image** and change **zoom quality** to *nearest* and disable *two pass rendering*.

In order to show pixel coordinates and RGB value go to **View** and check **Pixel Info**

Comment: Too bad it has a file manager built-in and scroll wheel scrolls between files not zooms (why?!?).

Comment: You need to press ctrl + wheel scroll to zoom

Answer (score 7):

The default Linux Image Viewer (as of now at least) supports the no anti-aliasing option: go to **Image Viewer > Preferences > Image Viewer** and turn off *Smooth images when zoomed out/in*. The infinite zoom-in is still missing.